# A possible Spanish origin for "lunch"

Tags: etymology, nouns

I have recently discovered the words of [José María Pemán](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Mar%C3%ADa_Pem%C3%A1n) from 1941 regarding the origin of the English word *lunch*. My translation (sorry):

> Wellington's Englishmen arrive in Spain, they fall in love with the Spanish custom of having a drink and some trifles at about eleven o'clock in the morning, that is why it was called "tomar las once"<sup>1</sup>, they make it their custom and take it to England, they disfigure the name omitting vowels, and from *l'once* they end up with *lunch*.
>
> <sup>1</sup><sub>Literally, "to have elevens". To have something at eleven o'clock.</sub>

This tries to explain why in the last quarter of the 19th century the word *lunch* was adopted in Spain as an exotic custom, even though that *custom* was something we had been doing for centuries.

But my question is, do José María Pemán's words have any credibility? As far as I know, *lunch* is [a shortened form for *luncheon*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lunch#etymonline_v_14616) which is of uncertain origin but it was already used in the 17th century. I am kind of answering my own question, but is there any possible link between the two words, like a boost in the usage of "lunch" based on the Spanish expression or custom? Or maybe the Spanish expression gave birth to another English word apart from *lunch*?

---

José María Pemán's speech can be read [here](http://www.letras.edu.ar/wwwisis/indice/Boletin%201941-35.pdf) (PDF, in Spanish). See page 53 of the PDF (page 435 of the original document).

Comment: I think you answered your question. Lunch was already in use before Wellinton’s Englishmen  went to Spain.

Comment: @user240918 yes, I suppose so, but as Pemán's word intrigued me I would like to know if there is some link of any kind (a boost in the usage of "lunch", for instance) between the two words.

Comment: Seems unlikely to me. Drinks and biscuits at 11 o'clock are called elevenses.  Of course, it's possible that "elevenses" post-dates Wellington, but a quick check of etymoline gives me no date for the origin of that word. But personally, if etymonline doesn't have anything like Peman's story, then I'd discount it as being a made-up etymology.

Comment: Peman’s assumption looks very much like  folk etymology

Answer (score 2):

The possible Spanish origin of lunch is *lonja* 'slice' which comes from French *longe* 'long' and ultimately from Latin *longus* 'long'. The original and obsolete sense of lunch from *OED* "A piece, a thick piece; a hunch or hunk." is directly related to this origin.

The etymology of "lunch" from *OED*:

> Perhaps evolved < lump *n.<sup>1</sup>*, on the analogy of the apparent relation between *hump* and *hunch*, *bump* and *bunch*. Compare ‘*Lounge*, a large lump, as of bread or cheese’ (Brockett *N. Country Words*, ed. 2, 1829).
>
> It is curious that the word first appears as a rendering of the (at that time) like-sounding Spanish *lonja* slice of ham. luncheon *n.*, commonly believed to be a derivative of *lunch* , occurs in our quots. 11 years earlier, with its present spelling. In sense 2 *lunch* was an abbreviation of *luncheon*, first appearing about 1829, when it was regarded either as a vulgarism or as a fashionable affectation.

The second and usual sense of "lunch" in *OED*:

> **a.** A synonym of luncheon *n.* 2. (Now the usual word except in specially formal use, though formerly objected to as vulgar.) Also: a light meal at any time of the day.
>
> **b. out to lunch:** insane; stupid, unaware; socially unacceptable. *North American slang.*

Eric Partridge strongly believes that the origin of *lunch* and *luncheon* is the Spanish *lonja* and says that *lunch* is earlier than *luncheon*. Here is a relevant excerpt from his book *[Word, Words Words!](https://books.google.ca/books?id=am9KCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT44&lpg=PT44&dq=lunch%20lonja&source=bl&ots=ywd0oCjsZG&sig=ACfU3U3wbhYWYZocfXTqCOHTg6PUo5uTmA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKs6X-mvDnAhUPCs0KHXhdBDYQ6AEwDXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=lunch%20lonja&f=false)*:

[image]

Ernest Weekley and Samuel Johnson mention the Spanish *lonja* for the origin of lunch in their etymology dictionaries as well.

---

**Bonus:**

The similar word *lounge* appears to share the same origin as *lunch*. *OED* mentions the North England dialect word *lounge* (meaning a large lump, as of bread or cheese) which is connected to the obsolete sense of *lunch* and to Spanish *lonja*.

*OED* says the noun *lounge* is from the verb *lounge*, and the origin is mentioned as "Of obscure origin; perhaps suggested by *lungis n.*". *Lungis* shares the same origin as Spanish *lonja*.

The etymology of *lungis* from OED:

> < Old French *longis* < Latin *Longīnus* apocryphal name of the centurion who pierced Jesus with a spear, by popular etymology associated with Latin *longus* long.